# Downloading videos off any site

Tags: video, download, streaming, video-streaming

Is there a way to download videos off any site? For instance, I want to download the video at

> http://www.livestream.com/etsy/video?clipId=pla_1463e546-47ed-4a93-b59a-bd52b236e8b8&utm_source=lslibrary&utm_medium=ui-thumb.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what browser you're using, there are extensions you can install that will try to help download videos streaming on the current page you're viewing. For example, for Firefox you can use [DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/).

Comment: DownloadHelper doesn't work with livestream.com

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox, I would say there is no need to use any plugin. If you use a plugin, the plugin downloads separately apart from what it is loading in the browser. You can save the video from the Firefox cache directory directly.

Open the URL which contains the video, similar to what you have posted above.
Then go to the Firefox cache directory. The Firefox cache has a temporary file which gets created for each video that is playing in the web browser. Save a copy onto your desktop or any other directory. Rename it to file extension .flv or .mp4.

For more information, see the YouTube video *[Get Youtube Video from Firefox cache folder without download](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xf8lV-MaiJg)*.

Note: If you close the window/page that has the video embedded in it, then the temporary file gets deleted from the Firefox cache directory. So do save the video as soon as the whole video is downloaded.

Comment: heys how do i search the temp folder for the files (there's so many) btw is this the link that i should search: about:cache?device=disk

Answer (score 1):

I find [xVideoServiceThief](http://xviservicethief.sourceforge.net/) very helpful. Unfortunately it does not list livestream.com as [supported service](http://xviservicethief.sourceforge.net/index.php?action=information#listServices).

Comment: that sucks... .